# Changing tree direction to horizontal

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I am using the following code that I found. I added color and letter size. But
I need to change the following that I am not being able to:

1. Eliminte the c letter in the edges. (red circle)
2. Create the same style of tree but now horizontal (example bellow).

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi] {standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest,tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  arn/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=6.5ex},
  arnrec/.style = {treenode, rectangle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,  fill=white, text width=ex,minimum width=4.0ex, minimum height=4.0ex},
  arnsmall/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=1.5ex}, root/.style = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  make f/.style={
    append={[f, arnsmall, tier=prez]},
    l sep+=-5mm,
  },
  make empty/.style={
    coordinate,
    no edge,
    tier=prez,
    for children={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!uu.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      }
    },
  },
  my x/.style n args=2{
    edge label={node [midway, #2, font=\footnotesize, text=black] {$c_{#1}$}},
  },
  for tree={
    arn,
    l sep+=5mm,
  } 
     [6, my x={61} {left}
        [1, my x={6,1}{left}
        [5, my x={1,5}{fill=white}
        ]
]
      [2, my x={6,2}{fill=white}
        ]
      [3, my x={6,3}{fill=white}
        ]
      [4, my x={6,4}{fill=white}
        ]
      [8, my x={6,8}{fill=white}
        ]
      [7, my x={6,7}{fill=white}
        ]
      [9, my x={9,6}{fill=white}
                ]
      ]
      ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For 1. delete `c_` from the nodes.

Comment: `forest` and most tree drawing packages are designed for drawing rooted trees, and your second picture is of an unrooted tree. So they're really not easily drawable with `forest`. For some alternatives, see [Drawing Unrooted Tree](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/371283).

Comment: You can draw the second with Forest if you take `(1, 2)` to be the root, say. @AlanMunn Do you understand how the top tree is transformed into the bottom graph?

Comment: @cfr Well if you take `(2,3)` as the root, you get the first tree but with fewer branches on the second level.

Comment: @AlanMunn But the content is different. If the tree is transformed, the content should stay the same, shouldn't it? You can't change the first into the second as the arrow suggests, can you?

Comment: @cfr No, obviously not. But the content is already different. But in principle you could transform a tree of the first shape into a tree of the second shape in the way I suggested. It also depends on whether you think the tree encodes just dominance relations or both dominance and precedence relations.  I was assuming the former.

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe I just don't understand the concept. Structurally, if it doesn't have a single root, it isn't a tree. So there's no mapping between the two which preserves the structure in terms of the pattern of relationships between nodes. (But you think of them as a linguist, which I guess is why you talk about dominance and precedence, which aren't concepts I am sure about here.)

Comment: great contributions Zarko and cfr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with `forest` is over my temporary ability, but solution with pure `tikz` is very simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, quotes, shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 11mm and 22mm,
  start chain = A going right,
N/.style = {% Node
            ellipse, draw, minimum size=5mm,
            inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
            on chain=A},
every chain label/.style={inner sep=1mm, font=\footnotesize}
                                 ]
\node [N] {1,2};
\node [N] {2,3};
\node [N] {3,6};
\node [N] {6,7};
%
\node (n1) [N, off chain, below=of A-2] {2,5};
\node (n2) [N, off chain, below=of A-3] {3,4};
%
\draw   (A-1) to ["${1,3|2}$"] (A-2)
        (A-2) to ["${2,6|3}$"] (A-3)
        (A-3) to ["${3,7|6}$"] (A-4)
%
        (A-2) to ["${3,5|2}$"] (n1)
        (A-2) to ["${2,4|3}$"] (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum (1):**
in case, that you like to have colored nodes with boldface letters in it, like this:

[image]

then only what you need to do, is add two lines to definition of node's style:

```
N/.style = {% Node
            ellipse, draw, minimum size=5mm,
            top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, % <-- added color to nodes
            font=\bfseries,                        % <-- added boldface to node content
            inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
            on chain=A},
```

**addendum (2):**
in case, that you like to your defined styles (used in other `forest` cases) then you only change `tikzpicture` options and names of node. in this case the complete *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, quotes, shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt,
                     text centered, font=\sffamily,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
       arn/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries,
                    draw=black, fill=white, text width=6.5ex},
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 11mm and 22mm,
  start chain = A going right,
every chain label/.style={inner sep=1mm, font=\footnotesize},
arn/.append style = {on chain=A}
                                 ]
\node [arn] {1,2};
\node [arn] {2,3};
\node [arn] {3,6};
\node [arn] {6,7};
%
\node (n1) [arn, off chain, below=of A-2] {2,5};
\node (n2) [arn, off chain, below=of A-3] {3,4};
%
\draw   (A-1) to ["${1,3|2}$"] (A-2)
        (A-2) to ["${2,6|3}$"] (A-3)
        (A-3) to ["${3,7|6}$"] (A-4)
%
        (A-2) to ["${3,5|2}$"] (n1)
        (A-2) to ["${2,4|3}$"] (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the image bellow is the theorical or book example that I want to implement empiricaly. But, it's the structure that the second tree has following my work. The main difference I see is that the image has no none or center point, it is more like a path tree. So I can not use the code above? need a new one?

Comment: for the showed image you need new code. i will see, what i can do.

Comment: @WilmerRojas, see new version of answer. maybe you will liked it.

Comment: yes, this will help a lot!!!. I will try to implement the rest I understand the time constraint. many thanks

Comment: @Zarko With `forest` I think it's beyond `forest`'s ability. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn, i still learn forest ... i found it very powerful and complicated too, but for sure it is not cure for all tree like problems. this particular image is far more simple to draw with pure `tikz` :)

Comment: Yes, the image is more simple. What I want to do is to keep the "style" of the forest trough the document if possible. So trees look similar. Or just used Zarko suggestion!!

Comment: what you mean with "style"? you like to have colored nodes? nodes are defined similarly in your forest example as well in my image, so add colors to my solution is more then simple :-).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add the `arn` style to the nodes in the Ti*k*Z case, so that if that is changed, it will be changed in all Forest trees and Ti*k*Z graphs just in the one place? It is just a Ti*k*Z style - nothing specific to Forest, so this is easy enough to use immediately.

Comment: @tikz, i add example with use OP defined styles. changes are minimal, however, as you said, now OP can centrally control all similar images.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method using Ti*k*Z's graphs syntax, but which does not rely on the graph drawing algorithms requiring LuaTeX. If you are happy to use LuaTeX, you can do much fancier (and more automatic) stuff. Also, somebody who really understood this could probably do this more automatically than I do, even sticking to pdfTeX. (I couldn't figure out how to except one node from a placement rule, so ended up placing them all manually. Even so, the syntax makes the code pretty concise.)

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,shapes.geometric,quotes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [nodes={draw, ellipse}]%, grow right sep=10mm, branch down sep=10mm]
  { a/"1,2" --["$1, 3|2$"] b/"2,3"[x=1] -- {c/"3,6"[>"$2, 6|3$",x=2] --["$3, 7|6$"] f/"6,7"[x=3], d/"3,4"[>"$2, 4|3$", x=2, y=-1], e/"2,5"[>"$3, 5|2$", y=-1] } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

If you wish to change only the structure of the graph and have it use the same style as your Forest trees, you can apply your Ti*k*Z styles in a similar fashion to your graphs. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,shapes.geometric,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% cwestiwn Wilmer Rojas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387249/
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  arn/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=6.5ex},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=15mm]
  \graph [nodes={arn}, edge quotes={midway, anchor=center, font=\footnotesize, fill=white}]%, grow right sep=10mm, branch down sep=10mm]
  { a/"1,2" --["$1, 3|2$"] b/"2,3"[x=1] -- {c/"3,6"[>"$2, 6|3$",x=2] --["$3, 7|6$"] f/"6,7"[x=3], d/"3,4"[>"$2, 4|3$", x=2, y=-1], e/"2,5"[>"$3, 5|2$", y=-1] } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: style-alike]

In this case, I would split out the style for the edges and use this style in both the Forest definition and your graphs.

```
\tikzset{%
  arn edges/.style={midway, #1, font=\footnotesize, text=black},
}%
\forestset{%
  my x/.style n args=2{
    edge label={node [arn edges={#2}] {$c_{#1}$}},
  },
}%
...
\graph [nodes={arn}, edge quotes={arn edges={fill=white}}] ...
```

and so on.

Leaving out the Forest settings as it isn't loaded here, this would give us

```
\documentclass[border=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,shapes.geometric,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% cwestiwn Wilmer Rojas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387249/
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  arn/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=6.5ex},
  arn edges/.style={midway, #1, font=\footnotesize, text=black},
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=15mm]
  \graph [nodes={arn}, edge quotes={arn edges={fill=white}}]%, grow right sep=10mm, branch down sep=10mm]
  { a/"1,2" --["$1, 3|2$"] b/"2,3"[x=1] -- {c/"3,6"[>"$2, 6|3$",x=2] --["$3, 7|6$"] f/"6,7"[x=3], d/"3,4"[>"$2, 4|3$", x=2, y=-1], e/"2,5"[>"$3, 5|2$", y=-1] } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to produce the second image above.

Comment: I am back with more trouble about the trees!! Sorry. I follow your suggestions I manage to present various trees but the feedback is that I need to organised them as the outcome of r gives. the error is only mine. Can you help me? please

Comment: @WilmerRojas Sorry, but I have no idea what you're trying to do.